# Getting an error:'No Button found with monkeyID "LOGIN" record

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, automation, monkeytalk

Getting an error:'No Button found with monkeyID "LOGIN" record

in recorded script in one project button name was Login but in another project button name is change to LOGIN. So script is failed. is there any way to run Script with name conversion(Case insensitive).Please suggest me, Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Arihant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Accessibility features of iOS (at least for your test artefact). Just set the `accessibilityLabel` (in the Storyboard) or the `accessibilityIdentifier` (programmatically) to a constant value (e.g. "button_login"). No matter what title the button has, *MonkeyTalk* will find it using the monkey id "button_login".